# Create to HTML from an output of bash script

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, html

I want to create a script to convert the output of my script to an HTML format.

Below is the sample output of my script:

```
[root@test tmp]# cat StoreOnceStatus.txt
spawn ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no storesvc@10.x.x.x
Password:
Last login: Fri Jan 27 14:44:50 2017 from 10.x.x.x

Welcome to the HP StoreOnce Backup System Command Line Interface.
Type 'help' at the prompt for context-sensitive help.

> serviceset show status

Service Set 1         Status
-------------         -------
Overall             : Running
StoreOnce Subsystem : Running
Virtual Tape        : Running
NAS                 : Running
StoreOnce Catalyst  : Running
Replication         : Running
Housekeeping        : Running


>
> hardware show status

Name                  Dev-id                                Status
--------------------  ------------------------------------  ------
HP                    300000000-00000-0000-0000-0000         OK
p0000 Storage System  0000-0000-1000-b0000-50000             OK

>
> exit


Connection to 10.x.x.x closed.
```

From that file, I only need to capture and convert to HTML the output of the commands `serviceset show status` and `hardware show status`.

Comment: What kind of HTML? Something fancy looking, or just plaintext?

Answer (score 2):

You can create template.html file which will be in form that you want.
And instead of real values, you fill it with some expressions (for example: SERVICESETSTATUS, HARDWARESTATUS,...) which will later be be replaced with real values that are collected with script.

In script you can use sed command that will replace expression in template with output command:

```
sed "s/expression/$(command)/" template.html
```

or in your case:

```
sed "s/SERVICESETSTATUS/$(serviceset show status)/" template.html
```

I was using something like this few years back for creating wiki pages.